# Kivy - editing label when button clicked

Tags: python, button, refresh, kivy

I wish button1 to edit Label 'etykietka' when clicked, but i don't know how. Have you got some ideas?

```
class Zastepstwa (App):

def build(self):
    lista=WebOps().getList()
    layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    etykietka = Label(text='aa', font_size=10)
    button1 = Button(text='aa')
    button1.bind(callback)
    layout.add_widget(etykietka)
    layout.add_widget(button)
    return layout

def callback (instance):
    newLabelText='kkk'
    #?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to pass your label to callback, a nice way to do it is to use the partial function

```
from functools import partial
```

change callback signature for

```
def callback(label, instance, *args):
    label.text='kkk'
```

then bind the callback like this

```
button1.bind(on_press=partial(callback, etykieta))
```

that should do it.

Comment: Well, i have callback method in the same class, so i wrote sth like that:
 "button1.bind(on_press=partial(self.callback, etykieta))", (also added 'self' arg in callback), and python gives mi error. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure you have the callback function indented and directly after the build function. Otherwise the callback function won be recognized in the bind statement.

Comment: Nice, i wouldn't cry when i face that kind of problem. Kip aware :-)