# Python - How to bind Button on_press on Kivy with multiple parameters

Tags: python, kivy

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339167/kivy-editing-label-when-button-clicked) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497629/kivy-template-with-dynamic-grid-layout) tags.
I have the error with function callback, the label has NoneType.

```
class Root(FloatLayout):

    def callback( self, label, instance, *args ):
        ## Try to pass Button.text to the label,
        ## but type(label) is a NoneType
        label.text = instance.text # here
        print(label, type(label))


    def load_content(self):
        content = self.content

        for but in range(65, 67):
            content.add_widget(Button( text=chr(but),
                on_press = partial(self.callback, self.lbl),
                font_size=20 ))

    content = ObjectProperty(None)
    lbl = ObjectProperty(None)
```

Comment: is lbl defined in your .kv file as part of roots definition?

Comment: I mada mistake. I declared `label` in the left part of Builder but call `lbl` from the rigth one.
`<Root>
label: lbl

Label:
  id: lbl
...`

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you are passing in as a value for label.

Are you getting a stack similar to this:

```
def my_callback(label, instance):            
    label.text = instance.text

my_callback(None, None)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***/vars.py", line 34, in <module>
    my_callback(None, None)
  File "***/vars.py", line 32, in my_callback
    label.text = instance.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

If so your source label is NoneType and you will need to track this down.